# Get a list of all DBNull cells of a DataTable with Linq

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, datatable

I would like to retrieve the list of all DbNull cells of a DataTable. Usually I was doing like this:

```
Private Function IsNotNullViolated(dt As DataTable, ColumnName As String) As Boolean

    Dim IsOk As Boolean = True

    Dim violatingCells =
        dt.AsEnumerable() _
        .Where(Function(i) i.RowState <> DataRowState.Deleted And (IsDBNull(i.Item(ColumnName))))

    For Each violatingCell In violatingCells
        violatingCell.SetColumnError(ColumnName, "Error, Violating Not Null")
        IsOk = False
    Next

    Return Not IsOk

End Function
```

But now I don't want anymore to pass the column name, I would like to check for the whole datatable. How can I achieve this with Linq?

Comment: If your DB schema prohibits `NULL` values (as your function is named) then you won't have any `DbNull` values at all.

Comment: True, but it's just for testing/didaptic/personal curiosity purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand your implementation by walking all column indexes using `Enumerable.Range`, like this:

```
Dim violatingRows =
    dt.AsEnumerable() _
    .Where(Function(i) i.RowState <> DataRowState.Deleted And (Enumerable.Range(0, dt.Columns.Count).Any(Function(c) IsDBNull(i.Item(c)))))

For Each violatingRow In violatingRows
    For c = 0 To dt.Columns.Count
        If IsDBNull(violatingRow.Item(c)) Then
            violatingRow.SetColumnError(c, "Error, Violating Not Null")
        End If
    Next
    IsOk = False
Next
```